# create pirate plot in seaborn (combination of box and point plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

There exists a nice plot in R called pirate plot. It is a combination of box plot and point plot. How can I plot something similar in python with seaborn?
You can find an example here: http://rpubs.com/yarrr/pirateplot

Comment: It's hard to tell what you really want, but I recommend reading the docs on [Plotting with categorical data](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the closest I can think of being like the pirateplot. Using both seaborn `boxplot` and `stripplot`.

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color=".25")
```

Resulting in this graph.

[image]